# Removing single/double quotes from beginning/end of string, only if they enclose it

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to use regular expressions in PHP to strip single or double quotes from the beginning and end of string, but we only want to remove them if they exist at each end of the string. That way, quotes used as measurements won't be lost.

for example:

```
"3' 7"" - would remove quotes
3' 7" - would not remove
```

I can easily do this with `substr` and `trim` logic, but I'd love to do it all at once with regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To replace single or double quotes and ensure that they must match:

```
preg_replace('/^([\'"])(.*)\\1$/', '\\2', $value);
```

Comment: Right, I realized looking at the first solution that it missed both types. In my code, this solutions works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_replace('/^"(.*)"$/', '$1', '"3' 7""');
```

Comment: Plus one for writing the exact same as me, but you were quicker ^^, Also you forgot to escape the quote in 3' 7 :)

Comment: Man, in hindsight I'm not sure why I didn't about this solution. Thanks!

Comment: I have to point out that this only matches the double quote.  If you really need single or double quote per what you specified in your question, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_replace('/^"(.*)"$/', '$1', '"3\' 7""');
```

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression way of doing it is to capture the quote and then refer back to it later. The stuff inside the quotes should also be captured, so that it can be used as the replacement:

```
$x = array('3\' 7"', '\'3\' 7"\'', '"3\' 7""');
foreach ($x as $y)
    echo preg_replace('/^(["\'])(.*)\\1$/', '$2', $y), '<br>';
die;
```

Now, the regular expression way is okay, but doing it "manually" is probably a little easier to understand and to maintain in the future:

```
function remove_quotes($string)
{
    $length = strlen($string);

    if ($length > 2)
    {
        foreach (array('\'', '"') as $quote)
        {
            if ($string[0] === $quote && $string[$length-1] === $quote)
            {
                $string = substr($string, 1, -1);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return $string;
}
$x = array('3\' 7"', '\'3\' 7"\'', '"3\' 7""');
foreach ($x as $y)
    echo remove_quotes($y), '<br>';
die;
```